# Can't boot linux because of Windows drive mount error

Tags: boot, 16.04, mount, windows-7

Formatted Windows disk C:, now can't boot Linux Mint (Ubuntu 16.04) cause Linux cant mount the disk during start up: seems disk UUID changed or something like this. It asks me to press C to continue, however seems does not accept any events from keyboard. Now was able to get to shell in recovery mode. Any solution, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Mint is not Ubuntu. Off topic. That said, a solution for future problems is adopting **correct practices**, namely: 1. Never mount the Windows system partition; if data sharing between OSes is needed make sure it happens in a separated NTFS formatted data partition, not in "Windows C:". Windows checks the system partition for changes and may not boot properly or not at all if something happened in Ubuntu while accessing the drive and corrupted it. 2. Disable fast boot in Windows 8 and newer. (...)

Comment: (...) 3. Avoid using Windows as much you can; use Windows only for those games and occasional software for work that have no native Linux versions or alternatives.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run `blkid` to get the UUIDs and make sure they match `/etc/fstab`(use `nano` or `vi` if your comfortable with that).